# Publish Vue.js + ASP.NET Core on Azure

Tags: azure, vue.js, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, cloud

I want to deploy my ASP.NET Core + Vue.js application in Azure App Service with a configured CI/CD GitHub account. I followed Microsoft's guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-vue?view=vs-2022#publish-the-project

I did everything as they said, but I encountered an error during the publish stage when pushing the repository to GitHub:

```
 > vueapp@0.1.0 build
vue-cli-service build

  'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\runneradmin.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.javascript.sdk\0.5.74-alpha\Sdk\Sdk.targets(171,9): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1. [D:\a\ThatsTime\ThatsTime\vueapp\vueapp.esproj]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQXWQ.png)

here is vueapp.esproj content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.74-alpha">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupCommand>npm run serve</StartupCommand>
    <JavaScriptTestRoot>.\</JavaScriptTestRoot>
    <JavaScriptTestFramework>Jest</JavaScriptTestFramework>
    <!-- Command to run on project build -->
    <BuildCommand></BuildCommand>
    <!-- Command to create an optimized build of the project that's ready for publishing -->
    <ProductionBuildCommand>npm run build</ProductionBuildCommand>
    <!-- Folder where production build objects will be placed -->
    <BuildOutputFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\webapi\wwwroot</BuildOutputFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

here is webapi.csproj content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <EnableSdkContainerSupport>true</EnableSdkContainerSupport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="7.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\vueapp\vueapp.esproj">
          <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
      </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

package.json:

```
  "name": "vueapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "node aspnetcore-https.js && vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vueuse/components": "^10.9.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "^10.9.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-editor-support": "^31.1.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0"
  }
```

I also tried to deploy using Web App + Azure Blob Storage, but nothing worked out. Can you help me fix the problem or maybe give some recommendations on how to deploy this in another way?

Comment: you're either missing an 'npm install' or vue & @vue/cli as dependencies. I'd probably run `npm install -g vue` and `npm install -g @vue/cli` in a separate script task before publishing

Comment: @Thomas How can I do that? Do I write this command in a .yml file or something else?

Comment: @Osminogka could you please make sure that your github workflow yml file contains this line or not : `- name: Install Vue CLI
      run: npm install -g @vue/cli`

Comment: @JalpaPanchal https://github.com/Osminogka/ThatsTime here is my github repository of this project

Comment: i have checked yml file which is located at .github/workflows/ThatsTime.yml i would like to suggest you to add this line of code `- name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install
    - name: Install Vue CLI
      run: npm install -g @vue/cli` before the   `- name: Build` line

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Do you think it will automatically process this command in the correct directory where package.json is located?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal  
It failed to install dependencies by running the command 'npm install'. The error message is:
npm ERR! path D:\a\ThatsTime\ThatsTime/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\ThatsTime\ThatsTime\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

Comment: Are you getting the same error locally?

Comment: @PravallikaKV I can publish this project to a local folder and host it on my local IIS server, and it works perfectly